# unique_ptr with vector: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of XXX

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, unique-ptr

I want to manage a two dimensional array as below:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int []>> vec(5, nullptr);
vec[0] = std::make_unique<int []>(3);
vec[1] = std::make_unique<int []>(4);
...
```

However I get an error:

> error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::__1::unique_ptr< int [], std::__1::default_delete< int []> >'

Comment: Is there a reason you are not doing `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`?

Comment: @Galik  No. But I just need an array with fixed size, so I use the raw array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the issue is with your [`vector` constructor call](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) (*2: fill constructor*):

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int []>> vec(5, nullptr);
```

Here, you're essentially calling `vector(size_t(5), std::unique_ptr<int[]>(nullptr))`. Note that this creates a temporary instance of `std::unique_ptr`, implicitly converted/constructed from your `nullptr` argument. The `vector` constructor is then supposed to copy this value you pass to it `n` times to fill out the container; since you can't copy any `unique_ptr` (even a null one), you get your compiler error from within that constructor's code.

If you're immediately replacing those initial `nullptr` values, you should just construct an empty `vector` and `push_back` your new elements:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int []>> vec; // default constructor
vec.push_back(std::make_unique<int []>(3)); // push the elements (only uses the move
vec.push_back(std::make_unique<int []>(4)); // constructor of the temporary)
...
```

To initialize a `vector` with some number of null values, omit the second parameter:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int []>> vec(5);
```

This will construct each `unique_ptr` with the [default constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr/), not requiring any copying.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int []>> vec(5, nullptr);
```

This line copy construct 5 `std::unique_ptr<int []>` from a temporary constructed from `nullptr`. It's illegal.

I think you want this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int []>> vec;
vec.reserve(5);
vec.push_back(std::make_unique<int []>(std::size_t(3)));
```

If you really want a vector with 5 nullptr, here is the solution:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int []>> vec(5);
vec[0] = std::make_unique<int []>(std::size_t(3));
```

Answer (score -3):

You are inserting integer elements where is expected array.

Comment: are you sure? I don't think so.

Comment: you define a vector that recieve unique_ptr for array **int[]** and when you use vec[0] it expect a int[] variable.